# How do I remove the blank space that remains after removing "logo" and "site name" and "site slogan"?

Tags: theming

I have removed the "logo", "site name", and "site slogan" from the Theme Settings menu:

Home > Administration > Appearance > Settings > MyTheme

Unchecked: [Logo], [Site Name], and [Site Slogan] under "Toggle Display".

For some reason, these things appear above the header and not in the header, so I am disabling them.  But, there is still a small space left.  It appears to be coming from a small div containing an anchor tag:

```
 <div id="skip-link">
    <a href="#main-menu" class="element-invisible element-focusable">Jump to Navigation</a>
  </div>
```

Can someone help me to remove this the "right way".. or advise me if I'm doing something wrong?

If it helps, I'm using the Zen Theme.

Comment: Quickest way would be to disable the div and the anchor tag using CSS.

Comment: @aerozeppelin Ok, but how do I do that?  Will that disable the screen-reader stuff?  Why don't you answer as an answer so I can upvote you?

Comment: I found the answer to what was causing the problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10536703/882146). Somehow, `margin-bottom: 1.5em` in the css for my nice_menu/superfish menu block was causing the space _above_ it. That's a question for another day. I set `margin: 0px;` explicitly for the menu block to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it in the CSS, {display:none;} or {visibility:none;}. As far as screen readers are concerned, I am not sure how they would work. I googled and found this [Link](http://juicystudio.com/article/screen-readers-display-none.php).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I couldn't upvote yet (my rep is too low), but I gave the green check. The link you provided is helpful.. though the more I think about it, I may try css to give that particular anchor (or it's containing div) absolute position which should remove it from the flow of the page. I will post my results as a comment to my own question. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the CSS file that has the property:

```
<div id="skip-link">
```

Find that rule set in the CSS file and add this line to remove it from the page.

```
#skip-link {
    display: none;
}
```

That will remove it from displaying on the webpage. If there is other lines in the decleration you can remove them or not.